# Create table SQL syntax in Google Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I've been reading the [bigquery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data) since late last night and understand very little of it. It talks about loading data via different methods, but doesn't say how to create the table that I'm going to load data into. When I use the web UI it expects me to type out the schema. My table has over 400 columns. I will not type out hundreds of column names, types and lengths.

I've been uploading hundreds of GB of data in csv format to a google bucket. The csv files do not have column names. I have the schema in sql format which I prefer to use.

If I try creating a table through a query I get an error already on line 2 that says,

```
"Error: Encountered "" at line 2, column 1."

CREATE TABLE [example-mdi:myData_1.ST] (
`ADDRESS_ID` varchar(9),
`INDIVIDUAL_ID` varchar(2),
`FIRST_NAME` varchar(25),
`LAST_NAME` varchar(2),...
```

How can I do this or what is the right way?

Comment: If anyone finds this, an alternative that I personally like a lot is MapD, which was rebranded OmniSci. It's open source at https://github.com/omnisci/omniscidb. It does take some decent hardware specs, but for my specific application, this is what I went with and they've only gotten better. I search over 400 GB of very broad data in less than a second using only the cpu (no GPU, granted I have over 500 GB of ram on the server and 40 physical cores).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create table in Web UI - you can enter schema field by field (`Edit as Fields` mode - default mode) or you can enter schema as a text (`Edit as Text` mode)
So, if you already have your schema in sql format you can just use it (you will might need to slightly adjust it to conform with BigQuery)

See more about [creating tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-sql-dml#bigquery-dml-create-table-web) with different clients (in We bUI section above option is not presented, so that's why you missed it I think)

P.S. As of today, BigQuery doe not support DDL - so `CREATE TABLE` is not available

> Update

As of today - Jan 17, 2018 - BigQuery [`data definition language`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language) support is now in [`Beta`](https://cloud.google.com/terms/launch-stages)

Answer (score 20):

You can use a [`CREATE TABLE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language#create_table_statement) statement to create the table using standard SQL. In your case the statement would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `example-mdi.myData_1.ST` (
  `ADDRESS_ID` STRING,
  `INDIVIDUAL_ID` STRING,
  `FIRST_NAME` STRING,
  `LAST_NAME` STRING,
  ...
);
```

Comment: Was this just added recently? I'm pretty certain it was not true a year ago. Admittedly I quit on BigQuery about a year ago because it failed to load my data in to tables after I spent a week uploading it. I managed to setup a locally hosted, single node server with MapD. I've been getting numbers crunched on a 400GB table in around 400ms where BigQuery was taking 2-4 s on a 30GB table.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE` was just released today. I added this as an answer in case anyone else comes across the question.

Answer (score 3):

Mikhail is right and gets credit for the answer. If you're as slow as me you're going to want more details, because after he pointed me the right way it still took a while to figure out what he's talking about and how to get it done.

When you're at the create table user interface click the "edit as text" link.

[image]

In the text box input that pops up you'll enter something like:

```
ADDRESS_ID:string,
INDIVIDUAL_ID:string,
First_name:string,
Last_name:string...
```

Hyphens are not permitted.

Comment: glad you get this :o) - thought it is obvious . next time will try to be even more detailed :o)

Comment: At first I hadn't noticed the edit as text or what it was for. Next I didn't know what to put there. I tried without commas and got an error. Added commas and got another error about a hyphen. Recreated the string replacing hyphens with underscores and it worked. I still don't know how to specify field lengths, but I'm guessing it just doesn't matter.

Comment: in BigQuery STRING is variable-length character (Unicode) data, so no length to be set

Answer (score 2):

As of April 2021, complex tables can be fully created directly using standard SQL (see the specific [syntax guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_statement)).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project.dataset.table_name`
(
    someName STRING
    , dateTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL -- REQUIRED or non-null column
    , index INT64 -- INT64 for INTEGER column
    , longitude FLOAT64 -- FLOAT64 for FLOAT column
    , arr ARRAY< -- declaring Array. This ARRAY is of datatype STRUCT
        STRUCT< -- declaring STRUCT
            a FLOAT64 -- the individual STRUCT members do not need the STRUCT column name again
            , b STRING
        >
    >
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `projectid.datasetid.tablename`
(FIELD1 TYPE, FIELD2 TYPE, FIELD3 TYPE);
```

Note: Enclosed projectid.datasetid.tablename inside backtick (``) not single or double quote.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE `mars.dev_project.sales_data` (
  timestamp DATETIME,
  Serial_No STRING,
  Entry_No INT64,
  Item_No STRING,
  Location_Code STRING,
  Quantity FLOAT64,
  Order_No STRING,
  Posting_Date DATE,
  Order_Source STRING,
  Order_Date DATE,
  Flag STRING DEFAULT 'YES',
  Created_At DATE
);
```

Also I found interesting this video, where he has explained 6 different ways to create table in BigQuery:

- https://youtu.be/tR0IXPBx6X8

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).