# 'Syntax error: Expected ")"' in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to execute the following SQL statement on BigQuery:

```
create table TMSPCBTDZOP000(
    ART_ID  VARCHAR(18), 
    LND_ID  VARCHAR(3), 
    ART__BEZ    VARCHAR(60), 
    ART_ANZ_ID  VARCHAR(18))
```

I got the following error message:

> Error: Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got "(" at [2:24]

I tried both legacy and standard SQL.

We are currently trying to use BigQuery as a data source for our reporting software (MicroStrategy) and it fails with the error shown above. The same error appears if I directly fire this SQL statement in bq. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

`VARCHAR` is not a supported data type; see the [data types documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types). Use `STRING` instead:

```
create table TMSPCBTDZOP000 (
  ART_ID STRING,
  LND_ID STRING,
  ART__BEZ STRING,
  ART_ANZ_ID STRING
)
```

You need to use standard SQL for this, and you probably need to qualify `TMSPCBTDZOP000` with the name of the dataset, e.g. `dataset.TMSPCBTDZOP000`.

Comment: thanks for your answer - i'm quite confused because connect is done via ODBC. In the driver manual there is some information about converting between BigQuery data types and SQL data types.  please see (page 20, very end)  [ODBC Manual](http://www.simba.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Simba-ODBC-Driver-for-Google-BigQuery-Install-Guide.pdf) it seems that the odbc-driver is not converting the data types?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking something like mentioned in old thread here
[Create table SQL syntax in Google Bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060768/create-table-sql-syntax-in-google-bigquery)
I found it useful and this may help you how to create a table in bigquery.

Cheers,

Comment: When providing an answer that is only a link to an outside source, it is best to summarize or quote the relevant info in your answer itself. Just adding a link is considered a low quality answer.